# Starting a script on xfce login and logout?

Tags: login, script, xfce

I use xfce4 as my desktop environment, running on a Gentoo box.  I want to start the pulseaudio server when I login.  In general, how do I get a script to run as soon as I login to xfce, and how do I get a script to run when I logout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have root access, you can always edit the startxfce4 script. According to the documentation:

> startxfce4
>
> The startxfce4 is a convenient script to start an Xfce 4 session from
>   the console. It will give you a
>   session with a taskbar and a panel and
>   with the desktop manager and window
>   manager running.
>
> All programs, or symbolic links to programs, in ~/Desktop/Autostart/ will
>   be run by startxfce4 on startup.
>
> To customize the behaviour of startxfce4, copy the file
>   ${sysconfdir}/xfce4/xinitrc to your
>   personal ~/.config/xfce4/ directory
>   and edit that file. If you install
>   from source, ${sysconfdir} defaults to
>   /usr/local/etc; for binary packages it
>   is often set to /etc.
>
> With the inclusion of a session manager in Xfce 4.2, the preferred way
>   to change startup behaviour is by
>   using the "Save session" option in the
>   logout dialog.

Or you can use the `xfce4-autostart-editor` program.

For the logout part, see the http://wiki.xfce.org/tips page for the personal logout script.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that xfce used ~/Desktop/Autostart.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the following which enables you to play login and logout sounds in Ubuntu xfce4.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649

Probably the simplest solution I have seen.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: exactly, Canadian Luke, because right now, "Ubuntu Forums is down for maintenance" :-(